# Discord bot programming

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am making a discord bot that is supposed to say no and delete the message when someone send a message that isn't yes. The code below works for answering no to when I send anything else than yes.
I can't find out how to make the bot delete the message.
I also would like to add more variations to the word yes, and I have tried this:

```
 if message.content !=  ['yes', 'ye']: and   if message.content !=  'yes' or 'ye':
```

But when I do that the bot answers with no even when I say yes.
Thanks.

My code:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print ('Logged in on discord as {0.user}'.format(client))
  print(client.user.name)
  print(client.user.id)    
  print('-------------------------------------------------------')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return


  if message.content !=  'yes':
    await message.channel.send ('no')



client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong syntax `message.content !=  ['yes', 'ye']` of checking if variable in the list.

The right test of membership is `in` and `not in` operators:

`if message.content not in ['yes', 'ye']:`

See documentation https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in

Answer (score 0):

This might be the answer to your question. Since I'm not sure what are you up to with the hello thingy, you may modify the messages according to your choice.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content not in ['yes', 'ye']:
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send('no')

    else:
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```